# Reading byte array to type/variable in a simplified way?

Tags: c#, sockets, arrays, tcpclient

I have a TCP socket connection where I get byte array of data which I have to decrypt and then format, so I am looking for a simple way to read this resulted byte array that I can easyly walk thru the elements exporting it as I need to a type or variable etc, to explain it better see the below example:

Let's say we have the byte array **(packets are little-endian, this is just hypotetical example)**:

```
01 02 00 03 74 00 74 00 69 00
```

I want to put the first 2 bytes into an int, the next 2 bytes into another int and rest as an string.

So it would look like this translated:

```
int first = 258;
int seconnd = 3;
string rest = "tti"
```

I am not a java person, but on java there was something interesting I noticed somewhere of people reading packets directly like this:

```
messageSize = readH(); // for 2 bytes
key = readH(); // for 2 bytes
message = readS(); // read as string
```

And I was wondering if there is similar pre-made feature in c# or any other resource that may help me better doing this task ?

Comment: How are you reading the stream?

Comment: @Nik I havent decided on that yet because I am not sure of the options I have to simplify the reading, currently just for debugging to make sure I am getting the correct data I am getting it like this `byte[] bytes = new byte[1024]; client.Receive(bytes);` and since I have a few steps like initial connection reply, then hello reply, then login reply... that I will have to format the bytes I tought of looking for some help/advices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `BinaryReader` like this:

```
using (var reader = new BinaryReader(stream))
{
    var first = reader.ReadUInt16();
    var second = reader.ReadUInt16();
    var stringBytes = reader.ReadBytes(6);
    var str = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(stringBytes);
}
```

However, this will only work if little-endian is used.

The example you posted is big-endian.

I assume that you implement both writer and sender in C#, so you are good to go with `BinaryReader` and `BinaryWriter`, they both use little-endian, so they will understand each other.

**[Edit]**

Another approach you might want to consider is using `struct`.
For example in your case :

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct MyStruct
{
    public ushort First;
    public ushort Second;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 10)]
    public string MyString;
}
```

The code would look like this

```
var myStruct = new MyStruct { First = 1, Second = 2, MyString = "asd" };

var bytes = StructToBytes(myStruct);

var myStruct1 = BytesToStruct<MyStruct>(bytes);
```

And two utility methods:

```
public static T BytesToStruct<T>(byte[] bytes) where T : struct
{
    AssertUtilities.ArgumentNotNull(bytes, "bytes");

    var structSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));
    var pointer = IntPtr.Zero;
    try
    {
        pointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(structSize);
        Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, pointer, structSize);
        return (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure(pointer, typeof(T));
    }
    finally
    {
        if (pointer != IntPtr.Zero)
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pointer);
    }
}

public static byte[] StructToBytes<T>(T structObject) where T : struct
{
    var structSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));
    var bytes = new byte[structSize];
    var pointer = IntPtr.Zero;
    try
    {
        pointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(structSize);
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(structObject, pointer, true);
        Marshal.Copy(pointer, bytes, 0, structSize);
        return bytes;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (pointer != IntPtr.Zero)
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pointer);
    }
}
```

Comment: that is very nice, they are actually in little-endian but on the example I just wrote anything that came to my mind at the time... was not any real example of bytes I get...

Comment: I would say yes to the BinaryReader approach, and no to the struct approach; the latter is a bit too implementation-dependent for my tastes. For example, BinaryReader is guaranteed to always read number little-endian, even if you're running under Mono on an architecture that uses big-endian (or if in some hypothetical future .Net itself gets ported to a big-endian architecture; I'm not sure what Windows 8 on ARM will use), but the struct approach will fail in that case.

Comment: @Sven - all depends on the requirements. Can't tell what to use for sure without knowing the requirements.

Comment: @Marc: It looks like `BinaryReader` is defined, though not very clearly, to be little-endian, e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.readint32(v=VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

For simple examples, you could do something like:

```
static class StreamHelpers
{
    public static int ReadH(this Stream stream)
    {
        int x = stream.ReadByte(), y = stream.ReadByte();
        if (x < 0 || y < 0) throw new EndOfStreamException();
        return (y << 8) | x;
    }
    ...

}
```

which gives you access to:

```
int i = stream.ReadH();
```

etc. However, *personally* I would be writing a custom `blahReader` (for your `blah`), with an internal `byte[]` buffer and tracking cursor. This allows *must* more efficient reading in most cases (even compared to a `BufferedStream`).

As a side-note, your string looks to be UTF-16 and read to the EOF; reading to EOF is a pain as it doesn't really allow you to encode *2* strings. I would (instead) be adding (first) the *length* of the string, and I would be using UTF-8 unless there is a good chance of large character points. Then reading a string is a case of:

- read the length
- decode that much via `Encoding.*`

As a final point - if you are *mostly* writing small integers, there are alternative encoding styles for integers that might be useful (allowing single-byte for small values, but still allowing full `int` ranges to be expressed).

Comment: initially I was thinking of doing something like that but I was not aware that I could use binaryreader like Alex proposed, now this is something I will totally to in order to help me out parsing/formating all the data. thanks. And yes it was UTF-16 nice catch :) but I do received UTF-16, ASCII and UTF8 only to complicate my life a little more so i need to check the initial byte codes to know the message size and type ehhe.

Comment: In that case, could you use a class with a 'bool addByte()' method? AddByte() would do all the checking and loading of data members and return 'true' when a complete message has been read,  Read the individual items in your protocol through properties.  The class could then handle any conversions - endianness, char coding etc. The message data is then encapsulated in a class instance and easily passed around or queued off to other threads.